# Lighttpd Mod_Redirect and Mod_Proxy to NAS

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I've setup in my lighttpd config the following:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/nas" {
    proxy.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "192.168.1.10", "port" => "5000" ) ) )
    proxy.header = ( "upgrade" => "enable" )
    #url.rewrite-once = ("^/nas" => "/")
}
```

This works as I expect it to, when I go to [webserver]/nas it redirects me to my nas, however the problem is that it keeps the word "nas" in the URL thus causing a 404 since it won't find the login page.

If I uncomment the url.rewrite-once it no longer works because it doesn't have the nas in the url thus not triggering the redirect. Does anyone have any ideas or is this so simple I am missing something silly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using subdomains. Worked for me
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-setup-adding-subdomain-with-lighttpd-webserver/

Well this didn't actually fix my issue, now it won't work externally since the NAS logs on at port 5000 not 80.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
proxy.header = ("map-urlpath" => ("/nas/" => "/"), "upgrade" => "enable")
```

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy